# How to enable debugging with barryvdh/laravel-debugbar only on specific pages?

Tags: laravel, debugging, composer-php

How do I enable [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) only on specific page. In my case I want to debug things even in production but only for admin panel

I tried digging in source code, but It doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/93

You should create a middleware.

Something like this :

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!\Auth::check()) {
            \Debugbar::disable();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).